# How did Wolframalpha calculate this integral?

Tags: integration, math-software

I tried it on Maple and Mathematica, but neither is giving me an answer to this integral

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(u^6+4 u^4-4 u^3-4 u+4\right)}}{\left(u^3+1\right)^2} \, du$$

Interesting in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoliumofDescartes.html, WolframAlpha gives an answer

I am guessing this is non-elementary and must use numerical methods?

EDIT: What method is used to calculate this integral? Is this elliptic?

Comment: It's not elliptic, but it is *hyperelliptic* (or *Abelian*, as some people might call it). Theoretically, this can be expressed in terms of a multivariate hypergeometric function, but this is unwieldy, and closed forms are overrated anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a secret society of time-traveling humans (coming from 5000s) working on that website. They can even integrate $e^{x^2-\sin(\cos(x))}$ in closed form!

Jokes aside, the fact that they gave the result as $4.917488...a$ (note the dots) gives me the impression that it is numerical integration.

Comment: Why is the $a$ in the back?

Comment: If you look at the parametric representation of the curve, $a$ is the scaling factor, so that you know that the length of your curve will be scaled by $a$ (or just to make sure, you can write the line integral, and verify that you can "take the $a$ out").

Comment: @Hayeder I think they meant $a \times (4.917488...)$, to be perfectly precise.

Comment: That's what I mean, why isn't $a$ in the front? Also what numerical method did they use?

Comment: I think it is their convention, I have no idea why. See for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FreethsNephroid.html (yet another random weird curve). In this case, the arc length has a "closed form" solution and they have written it down. I have no idea though which particular integration method they use.

Comment: So does this integral have a closed form solution?